# Iterating Over Strings in Shell Commands Using Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

To give a little background, I'm trying to put together a pipeline to analyze deep sequencing results of in-silico predicted CRISPR off targets. I amplify a known sequence from the genome in 50 different places and each amplicon contains a predicted off target site where my original CRISPR guide could potentially bind. 
   I input the two paired end NGS files into the program CRISPResso along with the amplicon sequence and off-target guide. The two paired end files, amplicon sequence, and gRNA are different for each of the 50 sites. I need to do this with multiple conditions, donors, and replicates so the numbers add up quick.

I created the snakemake workflow below:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

singularity:
    "docker://pinellolab/crispresso2"

SAMPLES, =glob_wildcards("data/{sample}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("outfiles/{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)

rule crispresso_run:
    input:
        R1="data/{sample}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2="data/{sample}_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz"

    params:
        AMP=config['AMP'],
        gRNA=config['gRNA']

    output:
        directory("outfiles/{sample}")

    shell:
        "docker run -v ${{PWD}}:/DATA -w /DATA -i pinellolab/crispresso2 \
            CRISPResso -r1 {input.R1} \
            -r2 {input.R2} \
            -a {params.AMP} \
            -g {params.gRNA} \
            -q 30 -s 30 --min_bp_quality_or_N 30 -w 3 -o {output}"
```

with the config file:

```
AMP:
  - ATAAAAACCATACACATTCAGTGGGAAACCTTCAGCCATAGAGAAGTATAGGCAGGGTGCAGCTGATTGCTCTGTCTTTGGGCAATTTAGCTTTTAGGCCAGAGGCCACAGATGGGTAGCCTGGTGTGTGCCTAGGGTGTTTTTGTTTGGCTGGCGCAATATTTTTTAAAACTGTAAGTTTATTGCCAGCATTTAA
  -GATGTGCTAGAGATGAGAAAGGATGTGGCAGAAGAAGTACCTATCTCTTGAGGGATGAAGTGGCCTCATTTCACCTACTGAGAGTCAGGAAGTGCCCCATCTGCAGCCTCTGGGCTGGTTGGGGTCAGTCTGCAGATTTTCCTTGCTTTCTCCCATGCCCTTGTCTTTCTCTCCCCTGTAGAGAAAGACACTGATGTTGCTGTTGTTCTAGGAACAGTGGAGACAACTG
gRNA:
  - TTAGGCCAGAGGCCACAGATGGG
  - CCAGCCCAGAGGCTGCAGATGGG
```

The -a and -g parameters in the shell command are where the amplicon and gRNA should be placed, respectively.

When I have just one amplicon and gRNA in the config file everything works great. But when I include two in the config file, snakemake just concatenates the two amplicons or gRNAs which throws an error. I'm guessing that I'm using the params function incorrectly but a can't find anything that shows how to use it in this manner (namely iterating strings in the shell command).

Also, just to clarify, the paired end files need to be run in the same order as each corresponding gRNA and amplicon pair or an error will be thrown by CRISPResso.

I'm new to all of this and don't know enough to solve the problem on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pair the samples with AMP and gRNA sequences, you somehow need to have the information about which sample pairs with which sample, so you need to know which sample names are possible.

Assuming the samples are named "sample1" and "sample2", you would change your config file as follows (not tested):

```
{
    "AMP" : {
        "sample1" : "ATAAAAACCATACACATTCAGTGGGAAACCTTCAGCCATAGAGAAGTATAGGCAGGGTGCAGCTGATTGCTCTGTCTTTGGGCAATTTAGCTTTTAGGCCAGAGGCCACAGATGGGTAGCCTGGTGTGTGCCTAGGGTGTTTTTGTTTGGCTGGCGCAATATTTTTTAAAACTGTAAGTTTATTGCCAGCATTTAA",
        "sample2" : "GATGTGCTAGAGATGAGAAAGGATGTGGCAGAAGAAGTACCTATCTCTTGAGGGATGAAGTGGCCTCATTTCACCTACTGAGAGTCAGGAAGTGCCCCATCTGCAGCCTCTGGGCTGGTTGGGGTCAGTCTGCAGATTTTCCTTGCTTTCTCCCATGCCCTTGTCTTTCTCTCCCCTGTAGAGAAAGACACTGATGTTGCTGTTGTTCTAGGAACAGTGGAGACAACTG"
    },
    "gRNA" : {
        "sample1" : "TTAGGCCAGAGGCCACAGATGGG",
        "sample2" : "CCAGCCCAGAGGCTGCAGATGGG"
    }
}
```

And here is how you could modify your snakefile to use this pairing information:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

singularity:
    "docker://pinellolab/crispresso2"

# SAMPLES, =glob_wildcards("data/{sample}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz")
SAMPLES = config["AMP"].keys()

rule all:
    input:
        expand("outfiles/{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)

def get_AMP(wildcards):
    return config["AMP"][wildcards.sample]

def get_gRNA(wildcards):
    return config["gRNA"][wildcards.sample]

rule crispresso_run:
    input:
        R1="data/{sample}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2="data/{sample}_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz"

    params:
        AMP=get_AMP,
        gRNA=get_gRNA

    output:
        directory("outfiles/{sample}")

    shell:
        "docker run -v ${{PWD}}:/DATA -w /DATA -i pinellolab/crispresso2 \
            CRISPResso -r1 {input.R1} \
            -r2 {input.R2} \
            -a {params.AMP} \
            -g {params.gRNA} \
            -q 30 -s 30 --min_bp_quality_or_N 30 -w 3 -o {output}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The config file you show should have a space after the hyphen, i.e.:

```
AMP:
  - ATAAAAACCATACAC...
  -GATGTGCTAGAG... <- should be "- GATGT..."
```

But I guess this is not the problem.

AMP and gRNA are lists so if you want to use the first item use `AMP=config['AMP'][0]`. (Then I guess you need some logic that assigns fastq file pairs to the correct AMP and gRNA.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think on the space issue I just got sloppy after deleting and readding those sequences a number of times. I could maybe add the sample names to the dictionary or put them in a csv, but is there a way to say like position 1:n for all elements of the list and loop over that in the shell command?

Comment: @ntrope see my other answer if any better.

Comment: @ntrope If you want to associate each one of these "AMP" or "gRNA" sequences to one of the samples, then adding the sample names to the dictionary (and possibly using a function of wildcards in the `params` section to extract the value from the dictionary based on `wildcards.sample`) seems better. I may be misunderstanding, but if you loop on these sequences for one given rule "instance" (i.e. for the processing of one sample), you will also get more output than what you want.

Comment: @bli this was the kind of solution I was hoping to use, but I'm not sure how to pair the files with their respective amp and gRNA sequences.

Comment: @ntrope I just proposed something (not tested, but I have used a similar approach so the idea should work).

Answer (score 0):

You commented the following below [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59344534/1878788):

> is there a way to say like position 1:n for all elements of the list and loop over that in the shell command

Assuming I understand what you want to do, you could do something like:

```
rule crispresso_run:
    input:
        R1="data/{sample}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        ...
    output:
        ...
    params:
        AMP=config['AMP'],
        gRNA=config['gRNA']
    run:
        for i in range(0, len(params.AMP)):
            AMP = params.AMP[i]
            gRNA = params.gRNA[i]
            shell('/path/to/crispresso2 -a %s -g %s -r1 {input.R1}...' % (AMP, gRNA))
```

(but I suspect there may be better solutions if you assign a wildcard to AMP and gRNA and let snakemake handle the loop)

Comment: I didn't really word that question well but I was thinking a method like the one you provided would try every instance of the gRNA and AMP for each pair of samples but only 1 of 50 of the gRNA and AMP sequences would be correct for each pair of sequence files. To restate, I was wondering how to get snakemake to input the two lists of strings into the shell command so that the order would be the same as the file inputs.